# display a balloon in android_version 2.2

Tags: android, balloon

I make some research in how to display balloon in a map.But i found the balloon only in android_version 4.0
Is that possible to display a balloon in map when clicking in a marker with android version 2.2

Answer (score 0):

I used [android-mapviewballoons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) in a project and it seemed to work ok.